# Require или include а может что то иное ?

Tags: php

Доброй ночи ! такая ситуация, есть сайт, в корне сайта есть файл index.php и папка contentCon, require и style. В папке contentCon находится файл contentCon.php, внутри которого между тегами

<head>
       <link href="style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <?php require 'require/header.php'; ?>
            <?php require 'require/nolix.php'; ?>
            <?php require 'require/content.php'; ?>
            <?php require 'require/footer.php'; ?>
        </div>
    </body>

как подключить стили и файлы php  как нужно прописать пути ! 
пробовал и "/" и "./" и "../" ! 
Подскажи те пожалуйста как это сделать ребята ! или может это как то по другому делается ! заранее спасибо !

Comment: $go = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

<?php require '$go/require/header.php'; ?>

Answer (score 1):

[@алексей поляков](/users/17619/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2), если я правильно понял, что у вас не подключаются php-файлы, то можно попробовать добавить

```
dirname(__FILE__).'/../'.
```

префиксом к каждому пути:

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../'.'require/header.php';
```

В этом случае dirname(__FILE__) вычислит текущую директорию, а '/../' заставит сервер заглянуть на уровень выше этой директории.

Если у вас запускается index.php, то c css и так все должно быть в порядке, хотя я бы рекомендовал добавить в начало слеш (/style/style.css). Это преобразует относительный путь в абсолютный.

Comment: спасибо за ответ ! попробовал подключается но как будто частично. то есть картинки, пути к которым были прописаты в header и т.д. не вывелись а сама структура вывелась, и при нажатии на значок, находящийся в header, который имел ссылку index.php стал иметь ссылку такого типа contentCon/index.php то есть почему то перескочил в эту папку и вызывается не из корня сервера а из папки ! может какой нибудь другой способ есть ?

Comment: @алексей поляков, у вас организация файлов построена на относительных путях, поэтому сложно сказать, где оно именно валится. Я могу сказать, что то, что я выше написал, никак не влияет на формирование всех остальных путей, поэтому, видимо, придется править вручную эти пути в файлах.

Answer (score 0):

Используй тег <base href="">
или пиши полные пути